# Difference between Euclidean and Hyperbolic lengths.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

What is the difference between Euclidean and Hyperbolic lengths?

For instance if i were to measure a curve on with the euclidean distance and alternatively the Hyperbolic distance, What would be the key conceptual difference?

In most cases is the curve on a flat plane projected on the surface?

[image]

Comment: The real difference is that Euclidean distance is distance in a Euclidean model while hyperbolic distance is distance in a hyperbolic model.  Saying "Euclidean distance is scaled by $y^2$ to hyperbolic distance" does not make much sense given that in the Poincaré half-plane model you do not have straight lines with constant $y$

Comment: Thanks, like the curve projected on the hyperbolic surface, the distance of that curve?

Comment: In a manner of gross referencing only the Euclidean distance is scaled by a non-constant factor $ y $  (not $y^2$ ) but if our scales are linearly marked on a ruler it makes no sense.

Comment: Note that the hyperbolic distance from $(0,1)$ to $(0,a)$ is $|\ln a|$. In particular, the "ray" $\{x=0, 0<y\le 1\}$ has length $1$ in Euclidean geometry and infinite length in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Keep in mind, the expressions $ds_{\text{euc}}$ and $ds_{\text{hip}}$ are infinitesmal length elements. To calculate the length of a curve, either Euclidean or hyperbolic, requires that you integrate these two length elements along the curve, and since their formulas are different, the two length calculations will, generally, be different.